# How to save used range as html file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement where I need to save only result sheet as html file so that I can attach it and email using vb scripting. I tried the following code but it changes even the name of the spreadsheet to the target html file name. Also, I need to save just one sheet as html and not all the sheets.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").SaveAs "C:\Work\Result.html", xlHtml
```

Comment: If you need only one sheet, then `Copy` that sheet, which will create a new workbook, and then save the active workbook.

Answer (score 1):

If you record a macro while exporting just the selected range to HTML you'll get something like this, which you can then modify to suit your needs:

```
Range("B3:C23").Select
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
    "C:\Book1.htm" _
    , "Sheet2", "$B$3:$C$23", xlHtmlStatic, "Book1_7762", "Export")
    .Publish (True)
    .AutoRepublish = False
End With
```